# How do I save different user settings based on their email address in windows forms c#, sql?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to create a login app where user information is saved properly. I've looked at tutorials which talk about using Settings.Default.Save(). However, these are unhelpful due to the fact that it only saves settings for the admin account (root/current/default user when the form is debugged and is first running). However, I need to create a different instance of the form when an email address within my database is entered, and retrieve the settings associated with that email address/account. I have already stored all email addresses in a sql database, **but am unsure how to save settings for each email address(user account)** separately so that different users can log in and have their settings from before.

[image: Here you can see] that I'm trying to create a new instance of the form for each email address in the database, but it doesn't seem to work.

[GetSettings and SaveSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmtbx.jpg) have already been used in the foreach loop, but it still only saves the default form settings.

Comment: I am not clear what step you're stuck on. Obviously you will need database fields to store the data... Is that where you are stuck? Or have you completed the table design, but don't know how to store or retrieve the data? Or are you good for retrieving the data but don't know how to initialize the form?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  As a general rule, it is better to copy your code into your post than to add links to images of the code.  Read this link for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I do not know how to initialize the form. I have completed the table design and am able to retreive the whole table data in a listbox for validation.

Comment: I don't know how to seperate users to their respective accounts. e.g. tims account --> membershipLabel.text =true; james account --> membershipLabel.text=false